# Masonry does not work with html added after loading (using js)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, masonry

i add html to the page from json file using append and then try to build the correct grid using masonry

```
wrapper = `
    //here html             
`;
$('#service_its').append( wrapper );
jQuery('.masIts').masonry('layout');    //not working
```

an attempt to do the same through the console does not lead to the correct positioning of the elements, but it seems to work, returns the elements

Comment: [https://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#appended](https://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#appended)

Comment: @imhvost Hi, not working for me (
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).append(...).masonry is not a function

Comment: Read the documentation! Or provide a reproducible example of code with an error!